# How does Stack Overflow keep track of its edit revisioning?

Tags: discussion

How does Stack Overflow keep track of its edit revisioning? Is there some kind of gem that helps out on this feature?

I know they are keeping the edit history in the database, but how does the application know what should be 'strike-through'ed, highlighted in green, etc.?

Comment: SO is built on ASP.NET MVC, not Rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow doesn't use [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails), but a [Microsoft stack](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/).

If you want something for Ruby on Rails, have a look at [acts_as_versioned](https://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_versioned): [acts_as_versioned: Getting started](http://blog.coryfoy.com/2009/05/acts_as_versioned-getting-started/).

Comment: Does this gem https://github.com/dkln/yesterday supposed to do the same as the act_as_versioned gem?